# Craft assets indexing wants to remove files that still exist

Tags: assets, index

Launching the task `Update Asset Indexes` in `CP Settings / Tools`.

At the end of this task Craft propose a dialog box for you to check some missing files that has been removed from the asset source/folder.

But for some reason my Craft is constantly asking me to remove some files that still exist in folder. And if I click OK then it ask me on each indexing task to remove a randomly chosen file.

[image]

One interesting clue is that this bug does not happen locally on my Mac Yosemite / MAMP local dev.

Charset and Collation look right to me:
[image]

Any idea how to fix that? (server/mysql config?)
Very annoying for me because I got metadata attached to assets so I cannot permit random deletion. It also remove the asset files inserted into entries.

Comment: What is the charset and collation of the database?

Comment: I added screengrab of tables collation. Looks good to me : utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 3):

This has happened to me in a couple scenarios:

- When I am working across multiple environments and forgot to sync assets properly. (i.e. I pulled down the database snapshot from production, but not the newer assets that would be referenced in its Assets index).
- When one environment uses a case-sensitive file system (e.g. a unix host), and one uses a case-insensitive file system (e.g. OSX). In this case, syncs and Git pulls may fail to differentiate between files with similar names, and both Git and Assets may bugger up.

Those are the first two things I'd double-check.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am in the second scenario (unix host in prod, OSX in local dev) but I dont understand how it would provoque the bug, as I did uploaded the assets directly from prod, and never updated those by git or from local FTP.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the folder on the server has a different name to your local version. The folder "songcover" has a space and is capitalised in the warning dialog

Comment: FYI Craft is displaying asset name and not asset folder, but its not very important, just a detail.